# C# - Writing a log using a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I am quite new to C# (I had an RS-232 problem recently) and am trying to write an small application which does various tasks behind the scenes and I want to create a log of messages to keep the user updated on what stage the application is at.

The log will just consist of simple one line messages.

I am currently using a textbox that is disabled so that the user cannot change it. I can obviously do multiple text lines using the \r\n characters at the end of a line, but when I come to write a 2nd set of messages they are written at the begining of the text box overwriting the first messages.

Can I change this to append rather than overwrite ? Also, will the text box automatically add a scroll barr when the text is more than the box can display ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
textBox1.Text +=  "new Log Message" + Environment.NewLine;
```

make the texbox not disabled, but readonly and the scrollbar will appear

Comment: All worked great and i had to enable the textbox otherwise the scrollbar wouldnt move, but read only sorted that out too !

Thanks all !! Brilliant.

Comment: There is a problem here. When the first log entry is added, there will be an empty newline at the start.

Comment: Nope the first line is used as intended !

Answer (score 6):

A better option is to use:

```
TextBox.AppendText(string)
```

for example:

```
myTextBox.AppendText(newLogEntry + Environment.NewLine);
```

Which makes a multi line textbox scroll to the button as well as to avoid flickering of the scroll bar.

[MSDN on TextBox.AppendText(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

To add it at the top:

```
textBox.Text = newText + Environment.NewLine + textBox.Text;
```

To append it:

```
textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + newText;
```

Yes, a scroll bar is added automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can append to the text using this piece of code:

```
myTextBox.Text += myLogText + Environment.NewLine;
```

Alternatively, you can use a ListBox.